# WIX Stores Show product images in repeater - error map does not exist on type [repeater]

Tags: velo

Im using WIX Velo to deisgn and code a custom product page for a wix store.

When trying to pull the media images (not the main media) im getting an error trying to put them into the repeater.

Error: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'MediaItem'.
Where 'MediaItem' is the Repeater that holds imageboxes named 'Media'

```
// Velo API Reference: https://www.wix.com/velo/reference/api-overview/introduction
```

```
$w.onReady(function () {
```

```
$w('#mediaRepeater').onItemReady(($item, itemData)=>{$item("#media").src = itemData.src
```

```
})
```

```
$w('#productPage').getProduct().then((product)=>{console.log(product);$w('#mainImage').src = product.mainMedia;
```

```
    const populateMediaRepeater = ()=>{
        const mediaData = product.mediaItems.map((item, index)=>({...item, _id: index.tostring()}));
        $w('#mediaRepeater').data=mediaData;
    }

populateMediaRepeater();

})
```

```
.catch((err)=> {console.log(err)})});
```